# ng build doesn't transpile arrow functions to es5

Tags: angular, transpiler

I have an old project on Angular 4, and this project needs to be compatible with IE11, so I added all the requires pollyfills to work on IE, also I change my tsconfig.ts file to:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I used `ng build --prod`, or `ng build`, `ng build --prod --aot` my vendor files still containing arrow functions. (`=>`)